# Is it possible to add values to a Hazelcast distributed map from the xml configuration?

Tags: java, hazelcast

I would like to add few values on startup to my map in Hazelcast before start using it. I would think that, if possible, it is done in the configuration xml.

My question is the following: is it possible to load values into the map before using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik there is no direct way to do that from the XML.

But what you could do is to create a MapLoader implementation that will load your predefined values and configure the map to use that maploader.

Comment: That seems to be the only way. I have also reviewed the XSD (http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/config/hazelcast-config-3.0.xsd) and doesn't have any tag to prepopulate the map. Thanks!

Comment: Just wondering, is there a way to do it via a Spring xml config? Would that help, if it was possible?

Comment: If you create a MapLoader implementation that receives a normal map build up in Spring, and you set that MapLoader bean on MapStoreConfig  maybe that might work. I have not checked.